# A non-associative three-valued logic

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lo.logic, quantum-computation

There are three elements: x, y, z and a relation C:

x C y,  y C z,  z C x,     x C x,  y C y,  z C z.

Let us introduce two binary operations with respect to the C: "the leftmost" (L) and "the rightmost" (R), i.e.

x L x  = x L y = y L x  = x,     y L y = y L z = z L y = y,     z L z = z L x = x L z = z

x R x =  x R z = z R x = x,     y R y = x R y = y R x = y,     z R z = z R y = y R z = z.

Similar construction produces a multi-valued logic, if to use a linear order instead of the C, but this non-associative "logic" also has some applications. Yet, I failed to find any notes about that in a book about multi-valued logic. I would be glad to know, if described construction was used somewhere earlier to provide correct references in my works.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Dear qubeat: This post, at present, is "not a real question", meaning that you've rambled a little about an idea you've had (nothing wrong with that! the best questions include some background), but never got to a question. Maybe your question is "where can I read about multi-valued logic?", but if it's only that, then it's only borderline for MathOverflow (I would expect Math.StackExchange to be a better fit).  Please read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask , and revise this question. If it is closed (and I expect it will be), then once you revise it, you can "flag for moderator attention".

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Trintercal?


Comment: Trintercal? I do not know.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd, thank you for the comments and suggestions, I have seen Math.StackExchange, but afraid it won't help.

Comment: The link to `mathoverflow.net/howtoask` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/157176) above is broken; the current version of the page can be found in the [Help Center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask). See also the FAQ on MathOverflow Meta: [How to write a good MathOverflow question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/883)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are describing a situation where $a$ is more true than $b$, $b$ is more true than $c$, but nevertheless $c$ is more true than $a$. I am not sure about the best starting point in looking for relevant references, but maybe *[Arrow's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem)* on the impossibility of a perfect voting scheme, where $a$ represents "candidate $A$ should be elected".

Comment: Yes, relation C itself is known very well due to rock-paper-scissors game, but I may not find anything about L and R operations (analogues of AND, OR) derived from such relation.

Answer (score 1):

Just few hours ago I found, that the construction was used in talks of J. B. Nation
“How aliens do math”, and “Logic on other planets” ([here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/talks.html)).
Despite of such titles, the works look quite instructive.

Comment: Soon after I posted the answer, initial question was downvoted. Anyway, I think, I must have sent an answer, if I have known about one.